# How to play a sound without creating a new player each time

Tags: c#, wav, audio-player, soundplayer

I'm working in a form project and playing a few sounds in some methods and events.
For example, in a method I have this one:

```
SoundPlayer sndplayrONE = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.wavsound1);

sndplayrONE.Play();
```

In another one, I have this:

```
SoundPlayer sndplayrTWO = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.wavsound2);

sndplayrTWO.Play();
```

What I want is to create only one instance of the soundplayer class at the beggining of the form code, something like

```
SoundPlayer sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(--some generic input---)
```

and then call it from any event, like

```
sndplayr2.Play(sound1); sndplayr2.Play(sound2); sndplayr2.Play(sound3);
```

etc...

I´ve seen some constructors like `SoundPlayer(Stream)` or `SoundPlayer(String)`, but I don't understand any of those. I need something short and easy, like the way I used to do, but without creating a new instance every time I want to play a sound. I have all sounds embeeded in Resources.resx.

Comment: Is it really *that* much work for you to create a new instance every time?

Comment: its not just work but one could also claim efficiency and code smells

Answer (score 2):

use a different constructor

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer myPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
myPlayer.SoundLocation = @"c:\click.wav";
myPlayer.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the information here: [MSDN SoundPlayer Class (System.Media)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx)

It looks like you can change the sound that a particular player will play by setting the SoundLocation property and then doing a Load() or LoadAsync().

It might, however, just be wise to make something like a dictionary to put a number of SoundPlayer objects in that you think are relevant for the current context. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer> sounds;

// Load sounds

// I wouldn't hardcode strings here, use constants or something. This is just an example.
sound["Sound1"].Play();
```